# How can I avoid Gerrit permission issues and migrate a GitHub repository to Gerrit?

Tags: git, push, gerrit

I'm moving a GitHub project to Gerrit.  I'm doing the following:

1. Making a new project in Gerrit with no initial commit set
2. Cloning the repo from  GitHub onto my local machine.
3. cd-ing into the repo directory on my machine
4. Removing the GitHub remote (git remote remove origin)
5. Adding the Gerrit remote (git remote add origin ssh://git.
6. Making sure I've got Push rights on refs/* in the target repository in Gerrit
7. Run git push origin master

I get the following error on running step 7:
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (prohibited by Gerrit: update for creating new commit object not permitted)

I've confirmed that my push/fetch remote are in fact the Gerrit repository I want to push to.  Furthermore, I've verified that I can make commits to this repository outside of my GitHub repo (e.g., I can submit a commit containing just an empty .txt file for review).

One other note: I didn't used to have this problem, but have been having it since upgrading Gerrit to 2.16.2

Answer (score 1):

When you execute "git push origin master" you're trying to push straight to branch bypassing the code review on Gerrit (this is the usual push to review command: git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master"). The "master -> master (prohibited by Gerrit)" means you don't have permission to perform this push.

See more info about this error in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-prohibited-by-gerrit.html).

Note: this is a permission issue and it's not directly related to the upgrade to Gerrit 2.16.2.